# Compose the sum

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two numbers, `s (sum)`
and `n (posit number, ii)`, there are several ways in which I can express and,
as a sum of n whole numbers, strictly positive.

for `s = 7, n = 3; 7 = 4 + 2 + 1 and`
`7 = 1 + 4 + 2` are not considered distinct.
I have to calculate i th solution.

Example for input:
11
6
5 
example for output:
11=3+2+2+2+1+1       (5th mode to compose the sum)

I tried to use backtraking to compose these sums but the algorithm does not produce all the solutions.

```
 static boolean checkSum(int sum, int remPos, int elem) {
        if (sum < remPos)
            return false;
        if (sum > remPos * elem)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


 private ArrayList<Integer> back(ArrayList<Integer> sol, int crtPos, 
  int sum, ArrayList<Integer> ans) {
        //the solution was found
        if (index == i) {
            ans.addAll(sol);
            return sol;

        } else if (index > i) {
            return null;
        }
        if (crtPos == k + 1) {
            crtPos = 1;
            index++;
        }
        for (int j = sol.get(crtPos - 1); j > 0; j--) {
            //add to solution
            sol.add(crtPos, j);
            //decreases from the remaining sum
            sum -= j;
            //check
            if (checkSum(sum, k - crtPos, j)) {
                sol = back(sol, crtPos + 1, sum, ans);
            }
            //remove from solution
            sol.remove(crtPos);
            sum += j;
        }

        return sol;
    }
```

Comment: What output do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: You must specify how the solutions are ordered, otherwise finding i-th solution makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is wrong with your code, but let me give you an alternate algorithm that doesn't use recursion, and doesn't require boxing the values.

First, you said that order of values doesn't matter, e.g. `7 = 4 + 2 + 1` and `7 = 1 + 4 + 2` is the same solution. In the algorithm below, we ensure that by stating that values must be in ascending order, e.g. `7 = 1 + 2 + 4`.

Let me illustrate algorithm using example of `s=10, n=5`, which for reference gives the following solutions:

```
10 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 6
10 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 5
10 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 4
10 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 4
10 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 3
10 = 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3
10 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2
```

First, build an `int[]` and fill it with 1's, except the last value is `s - (n-1)`, aka `s - n + 1` (where `n-1` is the sum of the 1's):

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 6]
```

That is your first solution.

Now we "increment" that to the next solution, where the last value is always calculated, i.e. the next solution is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, x]   where   x = s - (1+1+1+2) = 5
[1, 1, 1, 2, 5]
```

We continue that as long as last value >= second last value:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

Next one would have been `[1, 1, 1, 4, 3]` but that violates our constraint, so be walk backwards to previous value, and increment that. Since values must be ascending, we will fill the following positions with the same value (represented as `=` below), except we calculate the last value (`x`):

```
[1, 1, 2, =, x]   where   x = s - (1+1+2+2) = 4
[1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Next one is easy:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Now we can't increment the 3rd position from 2 to 3, because that would give us `[1, 1, 3, 3, 2]` so we walk back one more position:

```
[1, 2, =, =, x]   where   x = s - (1+2+2+2) = 3
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Now we have to walk back one more time:

```
[2, =, =, =, x]   where   x = s - (2+2+2+2) = 2
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

And we're done, because we can't walk any further back.

Here is code in compact form:

```
public static void compose(int s, int n) {
    if (s < n || n < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int[] values = new int[n];
    Arrays.fill(values, 1);
    values[n - 1] = s - n + 1;
    for (;;) {
        printSolution(s, values);
        int i = n - 1, remain = values[i];
        for (; --i >= 0; remain += values[i])
            if (--remain >= ++values[i] * (n - i - 1))
                break;
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        Arrays.fill(values, i + 1, n, values[i]);
        values[n - 1] = remain - values[i] * (n - i - 2);
    }
}
public static void printSolution(int s, int[] values) {
    System.out.print(s + " = " + values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" + " + values[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output from `compose(7, 3)`*

```
7 = 1 + 1 + 5
7 = 1 + 2 + 4
7 = 1 + 3 + 3
7 = 2 + 2 + 3
```

Output from `compose(10, 5)` is already shown earlier.

If you just need the i'th solution, remove the `printSolution` call, change the forever loop to loop `i-1` times, and return the `values` array.

Comment: Output for compose(11,5) : are [1, 1, 1, 2, 6]
    [1, 1, 1, 3, 5]
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 5]
    [1, 1, 1, 4, 4]
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    [1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
   11=3+3+3+1+1  , and  1 1 1 4 4 isn't a solution. After 1 1 2 2 5 should be   1 1 2 3 4

Comment: @Phoenix Output of `compose(11, 5)` is `[1,1,1,1,7], [1,1,1,2,6], [1,1,1,3,5], [1,1,1,4,4], [1,1,2,2,5], [1,1,2,3,4], [1,1,3,3,3], [1,2,2,2,4], [1,2,2,3,3], [2,2,2,2,3]`. Don't know what you're getting or why. `[1,1,1,4,4]` is a perfectly valid solution. and comes before `[1,1,2,2,5]`, which *is* followed by `[1,1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: @Phoenix For reference, output of `compose(11, 6)` is `0:[1,1,1,1,1,6], 1:[1,1,1,1,2,5], 2:[1,1,1,1,3,4], 3:[1,1,1,2,2,4], 4:[1,1,1,2,3,3], 5:[1,1,2,2,2,3], 6:[1,2,2,2,2,2]` and since you claim the 5th "mode" is `3+2+2+2+1+1`, then your "modes" are 0-based, as marked here. This is probably why you list `[1,1,1,2,6]` as the first solution to `compose(11, 5)` in your comment, when the first solution is actually `[1,1,1,1,7]`.

Comment: for input 34
 9
 366 the output must be 34=12+9+4+3+2+1+1+1+1 , and it's not

Comment: if the current step are 1 1 1 3 5 I need to take one unit from the " 3 " and put it on the left " 1 "  e.g. 1 1 1 3 5  -> 1 1 2 2 5 -> 1 1 2 3 4 -> 1 1 3 3 3-> and so on

Comment: @Phoenix If the solution after `1 1 1 2 6` is `1 1 1 3 5`, then next one is `1 1 1 4 4`, otherwise there are weird rules to your ordering that you haven't shared. Since `1+1+1+4+4 = 11`, and numbers are ascending, it is a **VALID** solution, so if not where my code orders it, where would it be ordered according to your spec? If you don't include `1 1 1 4 4` as a solution, then your are wrong, because it *is* an expression of 11 "as a sum of `n` whole numbers, strictly positive" *(quoted from question)*, with `n=5`.

Comment: I'm sorry for what I said before. 1+1+1+4+4 is a solution but it must pe generated before i finished with those sums that ends in " 5 ".The solutions must be generated in order, 
decreasing from right to left

Comment: Then you should have said so in the question, if that's what you wanted the code to do. I've showed you a way to do this, so perhaps you should try write code to do it. It just means that the iteration logic is a bit different, i.e. the logic of how to update the array of values to the next value.